# about Text Mining. How to save content at website?

Tags: r

In my recent research text mining.

This is my R code:

```
data <- list()
for( i in 0:8){
  tmp <- paste('&page=', i, sep = '')
  url <- paste('http://bbs.cyut.edu.tw/TopicClassList.aspx?ClassID=5', tmp, sep='')
  html <- htmlParse(getURL(url))
  url.list <- xpathSApply(html, "//table/tr[@style='height: 30px; font-size: small']/td/a[@href]", xmlAttrs)
  url.list <- url.list[-2,]
  data <- rbind(data, paste('http://bbs.cyut.edu.tw/', url.list, sep=''))
}
data <- unlist(data)

getwd()
setwd("C:/Users/user/Documents/doc4")

content_list <- list()
url_temp <- strsplit(data, '=')
id_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(url_temp)){
  id_list[[i]] <- url_temp[[i]][2]
}

getdoc <- function(line){
  for (i in 1:length(id_list)) {
    start <- regexpr('bbs', line)[1]
    end <- regexpr(id_list[i], line)[1]

    if(start != -1 & end != -1){
      url <- substr(line, start, end+3)
      html <- htmlParse(getURL(url), encoding='UTF-8')
      doc <- xpathSApply(html, "//span", xmlValue)
      name <- strsplit(url, '/')[[1]][3]
      content_list[[i]] <- doc
      write(doc, paste0(name, ".txt"))
    }      
  }
}

sapply(data, getdoc)
```

The `url_temp` has all URL.
I try to put in a URL in variable `id_list`.

But `content_list` doesn't exist all content. Where are errors?
How do I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved.

For everyone reference.

There are my code:

```
content_list <- list()
url_temp <- strsplit(data, '=')
id_list <- list()
for (i in 1:length(url_temp)){
  id_list[[i]] <- url_temp[[i]][2]
}

getdoc <- function(line){
  for (i in 1:length(id_list)) {
    start <- regexpr('bbs', line)[1]
    end <- regexpr(id_list[i], line)[1]

    if(start != -1 & end != -1){
      url <- substr(line, start, end+3)
      html <- htmlParse(getURL(url), encoding='UTF-8')
      doc <- xpathSApply(html, "//span", xmlValue)
      name <- strsplit(url, '/')[[1]][3]
      content_list[[i]] <- doc
      lapply(content_list, write, "corpus.txt", append=TRUE, ncolumns=10000)
    }      
  }
}
```